# VMWare Server 2.0.0 and vista 64bit DNS dosnt resolve

Tags: linux, dns, installation, development-environment

I have the following

VM with CentOS 5 running on vista 64. I have my DNS set in my resolv.conf (servers resolve on my windows machine and I have tried various servers). I can ping the DNS but it wont resolve any names for me. I have put some names in my vhost and those domain work fine.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Is DNS busted on this configuration?

Comment: I hope you mean resolv.conf. Could you post the output of dig google.com and dig @208.67.220.220 google.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an issue with Vista 64bit and VMware 2.0.0 at current there is an issue resolving DNS.

Solution: go back to 32bit vista... at least for now.